# One loop for iterating through multiple Lua tables

Tags: lua, iteration, lua-table

Is it possible to iterate through multiple Lua tables with the same loop?

For looping through indexed tables I can do something like this:

```
local t1 = {"a", "b", "c"}
local t2 = {"d", "e", "f"}

local num = #t1+#t2
for i=1, num, do
    local j
    local val
    if i <= #t1 then
        j = i
        val = t1[j]
    else
        j = i-#t1
        val = t2[j]
    end

    -- Do stuff
end
```

but how about key-value tables?

E.g. something like this:

```
local t1 = {a="a", b="b", c="c"}
local t2 = {d="d", e="e", f="f"}

for key, val in pairs(t1) or pairs(t2) do
    print(key..":  '"..val.."'")
end
```

should result in this:

```
a:  'a'
b:  'b'
c:  'c'
d:  'd'
e:  'e'
f:  'f'
```

Comment: Note: Although you didn't explicitly say you expected this, you should be aware that key-value pairs are enumerated in an indeterminate order. (Oh, and all tables are key-value tables; It's just the constructor syntax you've chosen that's different.)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. The order isn't important in my case, I just want to get all the pairs for both tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function pairs(t, ...)
  local i, a, k, v = 1, {...}
  return
    function()
      repeat
        k, v = next(t, k)
        if k == nil then
          i, t = i + 1, a[i]
        end
      until k ~= nil or not t
      return k, v
    end
end

local t1 = {a="a", b="b", c="c"}
local t2 = {d="d", e="e", f="f"}

for key, val in pairs(t1, t2) do
    print(key..":  '"..val.."'")
end
```

Note: this implementation does not respect `__pairs` metamethod.

Answer (score 1):

For the given example, I think it is much more concise and clear to just wrap the loop in an outer loop that iterates the tables.

I am assuming the primary reason OP was looking for a solution other than two loops was to avoid having to write the inner logic twice. This is a good solution to that problem and only adds two lines of code:

```
local t1 = {a="a", b="b", c="c"}
local t2 = {d="d", e="e", f="f"}

for _, tbl in ipairs({ t1, t2 }) do
  for key, val in pairs(tbl) do
    print(key..":  '"..val.."'")
  end
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

While it's always nice to have an iterator like Egor's, a more efficient solution would simply be

```
local t1 = {a="a", b="b", c="c"}
local t2 = {d="d", e="e", f="f"}

for key, val in pairs(t1) do
    print(key..": "..val)
end
for key, val in pairs(t2) do
    print(key..":  '"..val)
end
```

It's simple, concise, and easily understandable.

Comment: That is not what OP asked for. OP requested a single loop.

Comment: That's how I did it until now, but it's not that I just do a single print in the loop, there are more lines and I want to avoid copy-paste errors when I have to change something.

Comment: @816 Then I suggest you put all the code in a function, and then call the function I'm each iteration (still using two separate loops)

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to go with two loops :)