# Get disjoint elements from two tables

Tags: loops, lua, iteration

I am trying to get disjoint elements from two tables. My tables currently are defined as:

```
local t1={elem5=true, elem2=true, ...}
local t2={elem2=true, elem5=true, ...}
```

However it would not be much of a problem to change the structure to:

```
local t1={elem5, elem2, ...}
local t2={elem2, elem5, ...}
```

How could I get disjoint elements from both tables efficienlty? Also I need to know which table the elements where originally part of.

What first came to mind was to loop over both tables:

```
local fromt1={}
for k, v in pairs(t1) do
  if not t2[k] then
    fromt1[#fromt1+1]=v
  end
end
local fromt2={}
for k, v in pairs(t2) do
  if not t1[k] then
    fromt2[#fromt2+1]=v
  end
end
```

But these are two loops, so I looked some more and found a function for iterating two tables in one loop ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850100/6575359)):

```
function pairs2(t, ...)
  local i, a, k, v = 1, {...}
  return
    function()
      repeat
        k, v = next(t, k)
        if k == nil then
          i, t = i + 1, a[i]
        end
      until k ~= nil or not t
      return k, v
    end
end

local fromt1, fromt2={}, {}
for k, v in pairs2(t1, t2) do
  if not t2[k] then
    fromt1[#fromt1+1]=v
  end
  if not t1[k] then
    fromt2[#fromt2+1]=v
  end
end
```

Any more efficient/cleaner way to get disjoint elements from two tables in Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the first aproach.

1) You have to iterate over both tables one way or another; whether you do it in two loops or one is irrelevant.

2) You need at least two additional tables for the two result sets.

The one optimization you could do:

the `#` operator on tables is somewhat expensive, so you can sometimes improve perofmance by keeping a number variable and increasing it manually with each insertion. But please don't just implement this because I told you. Benchmark your code and only use this optimization if you find that your code actually runs faster.

---

EDIT: I just noticed that I kida skipped one possible implementation because I assumed you don't want to change either of the original tables. If however, one of the two is a throwaway table and you don't mind it changing, consider this:

```lua
local function remove_first_from_second(first, second)
   for key in pairs(first) do
      second[key] = nil
   end
   return second
end
```

Running this both ways won't work:

```lua
remove_first_from_second(fromt1, fromt2) -- Removes shared keys from fromt2
remove_first_from_second(fromt2, fromt1) -- Removes nothing from fromt1
```

Because at the time you call it the second time, `fromt2` already contains only the keys that `fromt1` doesn't have.

However, since this problem only affects the second call, you can get away with just one in-between table (assuming both original tables can be mutated)

Comment: The answer I was looking for is in your edit. Actually I came to write it myself. In fact one could remove joint elements from both tables in a single loop and get two tables of disjoint elements.